# DropDownList is causing an invalid postback or callback argument.but which one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I've inherited a ASP.NET webpage with over 2000 lines of code in the code-behind page alone. I get the following error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

This is my stacktrace

> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>      System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +144
>      System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +111
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +55
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +16
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +303
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1960

There are lots of DDL controls on the page but I can't seem to find out which one or what line(s) of code are causing the issue.

So, what are some strategies for tracking this bug down without setting EnableEventValidation="false"?

BTW I've never used the F-word so many times while looking at someone else's code. Because I've got Nested If statements in the PageLoad event about 500 lines long that look like this:

```
if (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "insertServiceButton" && this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "insertServiceRecord")
```

Comment: Do you create controls on the page via JavaScript?

Comment: All the controls are created in the HTML Markup.

Comment: Then any chance that JS code changes any of them?

Comment: There are a few instances of adding values to a non-ASP DDL.

Comment: Yes, one of the DDL's is needed to be selected in order for the page to be submitted.

Comment: Can you remove them and see if they cause the exception?

Comment: I can't remove it, due to the control being so ingrained into the operation of the page. I can try to hardcode the values though.

Comment: I hardcoded a value to be selected and still got the Invalid Postback exception.

Comment: Maybe try to turn it into ASP.NET DDL and hardcore the values there